# Problem uploading files via form HTML to CMS october

Tags: octobercms

code in html:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>file input</label>
        <input type="file" name="inFile" class="form-control-file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" multiple></div>
```

in the contact from:

```
 $infri->files   = Input::file('inFile');
```

and in the model:

```
public $attachMany = [
        'files' => 'System\Models\File'

    ];
```

And the file does not exist within the CMS system.

Comment: please share full HTML code so we can help you

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/function-form). You need to include the `files` options and set it to true.

Comment: public $attachOne = [
        'files' => 'System\Models\File'
    ]; 
i put this , but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" data-request="contactfrom::onSend" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-request-validate>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Your name</label>
        <input type="name" name="name" id="yourName" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
      </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox"  id="hidden1" name="hidden1">
        <label> Hide - name and your email</label><br>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone number</label>
         <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{10}"  required>
     </div>
      
       
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Copyright Infringement URL</label>
        <input type="url" name="url" class="form-control" placeholder="www.example.com" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Your message</label>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="say something..."></textarea>
      </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <label>file input</label>
        <input type="file" name="inFile" id="inFile" class="form-control-file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" multiple>
     </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">

    <button align="right" type="sumbit"  name="post" class="btn btn-success" value="Post" style="float: right"; >send</button>
    <br>

    <ul>
        {% for error in errors.all() %}

        <strong><li>{{ error }}</li></strong>


        {% endfor %}
    </ul>


</form>
```